# Add a boolean column with 1 if column value is changed and 0 if unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where i changed the value of a column if there were duplicate rows. if rows A, B, C, D are the same, then value of column E was set to 0.

Now i want to find the rows where value of column E was changed since the dataset is huge. How do i create this column?

Comment: `df[df.duplicated[subset=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])]`?

Comment: @BERA i have rows where value of E is 0 in the original data frame. but i want to find the rows where the value of E was changed, not just rows where E = 0

Comment: The column values are not equal to each other, i have 2 rows where if the values of columns A, B, C, D are the same for both rows, then value of E is set to for the second row. Now, i want to add a column that mentions that the value of E was changed to 0 in the second row.

Comment: @mozway i want to add a new column to the data frame that says “value changed” if the value of column E was changed by the df.duplicated(subset=cols).